# Python regex match string of 8 characters that contain both alphabets and numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string of length 8 containing both numbers and alphabets(cannot have just numbers or just alphabets)using `re.findall`. The string can start with either letter or alphabet followed by any combination.

e.g.-

Input String: `The reference number is 896av6uf and not 87987647 or ahduhsjs or hn0.`

Output: `['896av6uf','a96bv6u0']`

I came up with this regex `r'([a-z]+[\d]+[\w]*|[\d]+[a-z]+[\w]*)'` however it is giving me strings with less than 8 characters as well.
Need to modify the regex to return strings with exactly 8 chars that contain both letters and alphabets.

Comment: Where does a96bv6u0 comes from ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A more compact solution than others have suggested is this:

```py
((?![A-Za-z]{8}|[0-9]{8})[0-9A-Za-z]{8})
```

This guarantees that the found matches are 8 characters in length and that they can not be only numeric or only alphabets.

**Breakdown:**

- `(?![A-Za-z]{8}|[0-9]{8})` = This is a negative lookahead that means the match can't be a string of 8 numbers or 8 alphabets.
- `[0-9A-Za-z]{8}` = Simple regex saying the input needs to be alphanumeric of 8 characters in length.

**Test Case:**

Input: `12345678 abcdefgh i8D0jT5Yu6Ms1GNmrmaUjicc1s9D93aQBj3WWWjww54gkiKqOd7Ytkl0MliJy9xadAgcev8b2UKdfGRDOpxRPm30dw9GeEz3WPRO 1234567890987654321 qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'((?![A-Za-z]{8}|\d{8})[A-Za-z\d]{8})')

test = input()
match = pattern.findall(test)
print(match)
```

Output: `['i8D0jT5Y', 'u6Ms1GNm', 'maUjicc1', 's9D93aQB', 'j3WWWjww', '54gkiKqO', 'd7Ytkl0M', 'liJy9xad', 'Agcev8b2', 'DOpxRPm3', '0dw9GeEz']`

Comment: `(?:\b|\B)` has no affect on matching and can be removed.  Also, the `(?![A-Za-z]{8}|[0-9]{8})[0-9A-Za-z]{8}` is a wrong pattern since it can match parts of words longer than 8 chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the suggestion, I have now removed the redundant `(?:\b|\B)`. However, I would like to point out that I intended for the match to work on parts of words because it was never specified that matches are separated by whitespace. This pattern leaves it more flexible for fine-tuned modification if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```py
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b
\b(?=[^\W\d_]*\d)(?=\d*[^\W\d_])[^\W_]{8}\b
```

The first one only supports ASCII letters, while the second one supports all Unicode letters and digits since `[^\W\d_]` matches any Unicode letter and `\d` matches any Unicode digit (as the `re.UNICODE` option is used by default in Python 3.x).

Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])` - after any 0+ ASCII letters, there must be a digit
- `(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])` - after any 0+ digits, there must be an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}` - eight ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: can u change `\w` to `[a-zA-Z\d]` because `\w` it matches `896av6_u`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I added a second regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\b\w{8}\b`

It does not guarantee that you will have both digits AND letters, but does guarantee that you will have exactly eight characters, surrounded by word boundaries (e.g. whitespace, start/end of line).

You can try it in one of the online playgrounds such as this one: https://regex101.com/

[image]

The meat of the matching is done with the `\w{8}` which means 8 letters/words (including capitals and underscore). `\b` means "word boundary"

If you want only digits and lowercase letters, replace this by `\b[a-z0-9]{8}\b`

You can then further check for existence of both digits AND letter, e.g. by using `filter`:

`list(filter(lambda s: re.search(r'[0-9]', s) and re.search(r'[a-z]', s), result))`

`result` is what you get from `re.findall()` .

So bottom line, I would use:

`list(filter(lambda s: re.search(r'[0-9]', s) and re.search(r'[a-z]', s), re.findall(r'\b[a-z0-9]{8}\b', str)))`

Comment: I second regex 101. Great tool.

Comment: @benji However, it is not compliant with the .NET regex flavor. You can't use balanced constructs, nor character class subtractions in the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's find statement that finds words made of lowercase letters and digits that are 8 characters long:

```
\b[a-z\d]{8}\b
```

Next condition is that the word must contain both letters and numbers:

```
[a-d]\d
```

Now for the challenging part, combining these into one statement. Easiest way might be to just spit them up but we can use some look-aheads to get this to work:

```
\b(?=.*[a-z]\d)[a-z\d]{8}\b
```

Im sure there a tidier way of doing this but this will work.